# How to create a table with java-ascii-table to display testObject's field values

Tags: java, arraylist, console, ascii

**Question:**

How/what do I need to do to get java-ascii-table to display testObject's field values in given context?

**Background:**

This is a small program I build to test a 'Displayer class' I've been working on. In the application that I am building/test Displayer for, I'm reading data from a .csv, then assigning this to instances of Product & storing these instances in an ArrayList (it's like an inventory).

On this current iteration I'm using java-ascii-table. This small test program recreates my basic need: to create a table displaying, the field values (ID, name, category, price) of objects held in an ArrayList.

*Information on java-ascii-table can be found here:*

https://code.google.com/p/java-ascii-table/

*And here:*

http://bethecoder.com/applications/products/asciiTable.action

*This is the example I'm basing my code off of (It's the 5th example on the first link):*

```
//Example5
//The following example shows rendering the ASCII Table from list of java beans.

        Employee stud = new Employee("Sriram", 2, "Chess", false, 987654321.21d);
        Employee stud2 = new Employee("Sudhakar", 29, "Painting", true, 123456789.12d);
        List<Employee> students = Arrays.asList(stud, stud2);

        IASCIITableAware asciiTableAware = 
                new CollectionASCIITableAware<Employee>(students, 
                                //properties to read
                                "name", "age", "married", "hobby", "salary"); 
        ASCIITable.getInstance().printTable(asciiTableAware);


        asciiTableAware = 
                new CollectionASCIITableAware<Employee>(students, 
                //properties to read
                Arrays.asList("name", "age", "married", "hobby", "salary"), 
                Arrays.asList("STUDENT_NAME", "HIS_AGE")); //custom headers

        ASCIITable.getInstance().printTable(asciiTableAware);

//It prints the following tables in the console.

+----------+-----+---------+----------+----------------+
|   NAME   | AGE | MARRIED |   HOBBY  |     SALARY     |
+----------+-----+---------+----------+----------------+
|   Sriram |   2 |   false |    Chess | 987,654,321.21 |
| Sudhakar |  29 |    true | Painting | 123,456,789.12 |
+----------+-----+---------+----------+----------------+

+--------------+---------+---------+----------+----------------+
| STUDENT_NAME | HIS_AGE | MARRIED |   HOBBY  |     SALARY     |
+--------------+---------+---------+----------+----------------+
|       Sriram |       2 |   false |    Chess | 987,654,321.21 |
|     Sudhakar |      29 |    true | Painting | 123,456,789.12 |
+--------------+---------+---------+----------+----------------+
```

**My Code:**

*Main*

create instance of ArrayListMaker, calls methods in Displayz

This is the method in question:

- Displayz.displayProduct2(arrayListMaker);

This simply displays a 'logo', not important:

- Displayz.displaySurvivalStoreLogo();

Code

```
package playGround2;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        ArrayListMaker arrayListMaker = new ArrayListMaker();
        Displayz.displayProduct2(arrayListMaker);
        Displayz.displaySurvivalStoreLogo();    
    }
}
```

*ArrayListMaker*

Each instance of  ArrayListMaker has it's own ArrayList, testObjectsList.  testObjectsList is an ArrayList of instances of TestObject.

```
package playGround2;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayListMaker {
    public ArrayList<TestObject> testObjectsList;

    public ArrayListMaker() {
        testObjectsList = new ArrayList<TestObject>();

        testObjectsList.add( new TestObject("11","One", "This", "10"));
        testObjectsList.add( new TestObject("12", "Two", "That", "20"));
        testObjectsList.add( new TestObject("13", "Three", "Other", "30"));
        testObjectsList.add( new TestObject("14", "four", "something", "40"));
        testObjectsList.add( new TestObject("15", "five", "else", "50"));
        testObjectsList.add( new TestObject("16", "six", "over-there", "60"));
        testObjectsList.add( new TestObject("17", "seven", "Who", "70"));
        testObjectsList.add( new TestObject("18", "eight", "Why", "80"));
    }

    public ArrayList<TestObject> getTestObjects() {
        return this.testObjectsList;
    }
}
```

*TestObject*

POJO.  Fields for: ID, name, catagory, price...setters, getters, etc...

```
package playGround2;

public class TestObject {
    private String ID;
    private String name;
    private String category;
    private String price;

/********************constructors********************/

    public TestObject() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public TestObject(String ID, String name, String category, String price) {
        this.setID(ID);
        this.setName(name);
        this.setCategory(category);
        this.setPrice(price);
    }

/********************get & set********************/

/**********ID**********/
    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(String iD) {
        ID = iD;
    }

/**********name**********/

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

/**********category**********/

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

/**********price**********/

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

*Displayz*

Has methods for displaying data(& a 'logo').

This is the method I need to create the table.  I have written some code based the above example.  But since this is new to me, I might be way off.

- displayProduct2()

Code

```
package playGround2;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import com.bethecoder.ascii_table.ASCIITable;
import com.bethecoder.ascii_table.impl.*;
import com.bethecoder.ascii_table.spec.*;

public class Displayz {

    public static void displaySurvivalStoreLogo() {
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(144, 32, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        Graphics graphics = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
        graphics.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 24));

        Graphics2D graphics2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;
        graphics2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        graphics2d.drawString("SurvivalStore", 6, 24);

        try {
            ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", new File("text.png"));
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (int y = 0; y < 32; y++) {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            for (int x = 0; x < 144; x++) {
                stringBuilder.append(bufferedImage.getRGB(x, y) == -16777216 ? " " : bufferedImage.getRGB(x, y) == -1 ? "#" : "*");
            }

            if (stringBuilder.toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                continue;
            }

            System.out.println(stringBuilder);
        }
    } //end of displaySurvivalStore

   public static void displayProduct2(ArrayListMaker arrayListMaker) {          
         IASCIITableAware asciiTableAware = new CollectionASCIITableAware<TestObject>(arrayListMaker.getTestObjects(),"ID", "name", "category", "price"); 
         ASCIITable.getInstance().printTable(asciiTableAware);

        // In this argument(Arrays.asList("name", "category", "price")), Arrays in underlined in red
        asciiTableAware = new CollectionASCIITableAware<TestObject>(arrayListMaker.getTestObjects(), Arrays.asList("ID", "name", "category", "price"), ASCIITable.getInstance().printTable(asciiTableAware);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you problem boils down to this line...

```
asciiTableAware = new CollectionASCIITableAware<TestObject>(arrayListMaker.getTestObjects(), Arrays.asList("ID", "name", "category", "price"), ASCIITable.getInstance().printTable(asciiTableAware);
```

There is no constructor for `List<?>, List<String>, void` (and you left off a tailing `)`... You've merged to lines of code by accident

It should be something more like...

```
asciiTableAware = new CollectionASCIITableAware<TestObject>(arrayListMaker.getTestObjects(), Arrays.asList("ID", "name", "category", "price"));
ASCIITable.getInstance().printTable(asciiTableAware);
```

But wait, there's no constructor for `List<?>, List<String>` either?!?  It needs one last parameter, a `List<String>` which represents the titles...

```
asciiTableAware = new CollectionASCIITableAware<TestObject>(testObjectsList, Arrays.asList("id", "name", "category", "price"), Arrays.asList("A ID", "First Name", "The Category", "Payup"));
ASCIITable.getInstance().printTable(asciiTableAware);
```

Ah, now it compiles...

But wait, when we run it...

```
+------+-------+------------+-------+
|  ID  |  NAME |  CATEGORY  | PRICE |
+------+-------+------------+-------+
| null |   One |       This |    10 |
| null |   Two |       That |    20 |
| null | Three |      Other |    30 |
| null |  four |  something |    40 |
| null |  five |       else |    50 |
| null |   six | over-there |    60 |
| null | seven |        Who |    70 |
| null | eight |        Why |    80 |
+------+-------+------------+-------+

+------+------------+--------------+-------+
| A ID | FIRST NAME | THE CATEGORY | PAYUP |
+------+------------+--------------+-------+
| null |        One |         This |    10 |
| null |        Two |         That |    20 |
| null |      Three |        Other |    30 |
| null |       four |    something |    40 |
| null |       five |         else |    50 |
| null |        six |   over-there |    60 |
| null |      seven |          Who |    70 |
| null |      eight |          Why |    80 |
+------+------------+--------------+-------+
```

Why are we getting `null` for `ID`??!?

The API follows the Java Bean/coding conventions for method names, [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html) and [JavaBeans](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/beans.101.pdf?AuthParam=1436230186_585bbd888c14028ba31c69de90c05b80), this means that it's actually expecting `ID` to be `Id`

So if we change the set and get methods of `TestObject` to be `setId` and `getId` and run it again, we get

```
+----+-------+------------+-------+
| ID |  NAME |  CATEGORY  | PRICE |
+----+-------+------------+-------+
| 11 |   One |       This |    10 |
| 12 |   Two |       That |    20 |
| 13 | Three |      Other |    30 |
| 14 |  four |  something |    40 |
| 15 |  five |       else |    50 |
| 16 |   six | over-there |    60 |
| 17 | seven |        Who |    70 |
| 18 | eight |        Why |    80 |
+----+-------+------------+-------+

+------+------------+--------------+-------+
| A ID | FIRST NAME | THE CATEGORY | PAYUP |
+------+------------+--------------+-------+
|   11 |        One |         This |    10 |
|   12 |        Two |         That |    20 |
|   13 |      Three |        Other |    30 |
|   14 |       four |    something |    40 |
|   15 |       five |         else |    50 |
|   16 |        six |   over-there |    60 |
|   17 |      seven |          Who |    70 |
|   18 |      eight |          Why |    80 |
+------+------------+--------------+-------+
```

Comment: 2 thumbs way up!  Thank you for the meaningful & thoughtful reply.